# How to clear and override table result

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have initial value on my table and I created a button that supposedly clear and override new value to my table. But what happening in my current script is if I clicked my button the table will just append a new row.

Here is my current loader:

```
function RefreshData() {

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/GetItemList',
            type: 'GET',

            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                var row = '';
                $('.table tbody').html("");
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    row += '<tr><td style="display:none;"  >' + item.empSerial + '</td><td width="50%">' + item.name
                        + '</td><td width="30%">' + item.dept
                        + '</td><td style="display:none;"  >' + item.fname
                        + '</td><td style="display:none;"  >' + item.lname
                        + '</td><td>' + '<button onclick="delete(this, ' + item.empSerial + ",'" + item.name + "'" + ')" type="button" class="btn btn-danger"> Remove </button >'
                        + '</td><td>' + '<button onclick="update(this, ' + item.empSerial + ",'" + item.fname + ",'" + item.lname + ",'" + item.dept + ",'" + item.name + "'" + ')" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalPMA"> Update </button >' + '</td></tr>';

                });
                $('.table tbody').html(row); // override previous results
            },

            error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(errorThrown.toString());
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`table` is a element not a class `.table` so remove dot `.` from it.

```
$('table tbody').html("");
```